# Error handing in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-7, error-handling, try-catch

i have a big project in asp.net & c# (not MVC). in whole project i forget to handle *throw* in each and every *try catch* block. 
now the problem is : if any error occur then page shows that error. what i want to do is if any Error occurs and goes to *throw* i want the page to be redirected to the specific page [user friendly message on that page.].

how can i do this? 
can i write anything that redirect the error page to other url?
is there any way to handle it in IIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set some properties in the `Web.config` file to handle uncaught errors

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="/errors/error">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="/errors/error404" />
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="/errors/error500" />
</customErrors>
```

The above setup loads the `/errors/error` page, but you can set a different page for a different error.

Further more, if you want to handle all uncaught errors, e.g. for logging purposes, you can put this code in your `Global.asax` file.

```
public void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    // Do something with ex
}
```

Comment: I also found something that might help someone Custom Error handling : http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs

Comment: I have written these two relevant articles. One is about hiding server errors http://codingstill.com/2011/05/handling-redirections-missing-pages-and-server-errors-in-asp-net/ and the other is about handling server errors http://codingstill.com/2011/09/handling-server-errors-in-asp-net/. Take a look in the first article, the `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors` might be useful for your case